Error "missed interaction because MapUe3Logger was not yet initialized" when trying to click a marker
I'm using Google Maps SDK v3 in my android app, and when I try to click on the marker with custom InfoWindow I get some weird logs in logcat:
missed interaction because MapUe3Logger was not yet initialized                                                                                          ebe                                                             
at ebg.b(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@221110601@221110601072.437244185.437244185:0)
at czr.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@221110601@221110601072.437244185.437244185:5)                                                  
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)                                                  
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)                                                          
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)                                                              
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)                                                                                      
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)                                                                        
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                   
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

there is code of MapsFragment:
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment {

  private final OnMapReadyCallback callback = googleMap -> {
    showTripPaths(googleMap);

    googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this::markerClickListener);
  };

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable ViewGroup container,
      @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
  }

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
        (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (mapFragment != null) {
      mapFragment.getMapAsync(callback);
    }

    mapsViewModel =
        new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MapsViewModel.class);
  }

  private boolean markerClickListener(Marker m) {
    if (m.isInfoWindowShown()) {
      m.hideInfoWindow();
    } else {
      m.showInfoWindow();
    }
    return true;
  }

  private void showTripPaths(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // put markers on map
  }

  class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    private final View contents;

    CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
      contents = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(@NonNull Marker marker) {
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(@NonNull Marker marker) {
      render(marker, contents);
      return contents;
    }

    private void render(Marker marker, View view) {
      TextView titleTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
      TextView snippetTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
      ImageView tripPhotoView = view.findViewById(R.id.tripImage);
      Button showTripButton = view.findViewById(R.id.showTripButton);
      // setting text
  }
}

there is custom_info_contens.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:text="trip title"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
  <ImageView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tripImage"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:src="@drawable/kazantip"/>
  <TextView
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/snippet"
    android:text="trip snippet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#ff7f7f7f"
    android:textSize="14dp" />
  <Button
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:id="@+id/showTripButton"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:text="show trip"
    android:textSize="13sp" />
</LinearLayout>

I have such dependencies in my gradle:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin")
}

//...

dependencies {
    //...
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.2.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.libraries.places:places:3.4.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.3.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.libraries.identity.googleid:googleid:1.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0")
}

When I click on the marker I get that error in logs several times without appearing InfoWindow, and logs said
allocateBlock - Allocation still failed after resize. And only then InfoWindow appears with log message successfully allocated.
How can I fix this issue?

Please make sure that your device is running on the latest version of Google Play Services and you're using the Latest Renderer.
